# two rich:ajax conflict problems (in 3 rich:select controls)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, richfaces

I have 3 rich:select controls which have id select1, select2, select3.I want to click on select1, control “select2” will be rendered, and when I click on control select2, select3 will be rendered, like this. I made my application by netbeans 7.0.1, and use framework jsf 2.0, and richFaces 4.2.0.

My solution is to create two a4j:ajax which have id ajax1 and ajax2, to assign the render of select2 and select3 base on select1 and select2 selectItem event. I have arranged ajax1 and ajax2 in a queue which have id queue1.

Here is the code of the page:

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:queue name="queue1"  onerror="window.alert('alert in queue');" onrequestdequeue="window.alert('queue1 dequeue');" onrequestqueue="window.alert('queue1 enqueue');" requestDelay="1000" ignoreDupResponses="true"/>
     <h3 style="text-align: center">Test case 1: 3 selection controls problem</h3>

     <br/><br/>
    <h:outputLink value="../index.xhtml">View Index </h:outputLink>
    <br/><br/>
     Problem: <h:outputText escape="false" value="#{carBean.testDescription}"/>
    <br/><br/>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Car Firm (selection1)</td>
            <td>Car type (selection2)</td>
            <td>Production (selection3)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
        <rich:select id="select1" value="#{carBean.companyName}" maxListHeight="100"  enableManualInput="true"  defaultLabel="Type here">      
            <a4j:ajax id="ajax1" queueId="queue1" execute="@form" render="select2, errorText" event="selectitem"  listener="#{carBean.changeCompanyEvent()}">

            </a4j:ajax>                                
            <f:selectItems value="#{carBean.lstCompany}"></f:selectItems>
        </rich:select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <rich:select id="select2" value="#{carBean.typeName}"  maxListHeight="100"  enableManualInput="true" defaultLabel="Type here"  >      
            <a4j:ajax id="ajax2" queueId="queue1"  immediate="true"  execute="@form" render="select3, errorText" event="selectitem"  listener="#{carBean.changeCarTypeEvent()}">

            </a4j:ajax>                                
            <f:selectItems value="#{carBean.lstCarType}"></f:selectItems>
        </rich:select>
        </td>
        <td>
        <rich:select id="select3" value="#{carBean.productionName}" 
                     maxListHeight="100"  enableManualInput="true" defaultLabel="Type here"  >                                              
            <f:selectItems  value="#{carBean.lstCarProduction}"></f:selectItems>
        </rich:select>
        </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/><br/>
    <h:outputText id="errorText" escape="false" value="#{carBean.alertError}"/>

</h:form>
```

Problems encountered: I have 2 problems that I still not found reasons yet:

- The select2 has to set immediate = true, otherwise the event defined in ajax2 will not done.

I don’t know what cause this.

- When I set immediate = true for select2, the ajax2 event was called. But the typeName variable, which is assigned as value of select2 control, still not assigned a value is selected, so select3 has not been assigned a value yet.

Here is the error images: http://i970.photobucket.com/albums/ae190/swenteiger7/richFaces%20error-%20110312/testcase1Error.png

**Application**: I also sent my application project (opened by net beans IDE) to get along with this question. You can concentrate in 3 items:
-   The faces-config.xml file in Web/Web-INF folder, which defined CarBean managed Bean
-   The testcase1 folder in web folder (which have threeSelectExample.xhtml).
-   The beans package and utils package to save managed bean (in testcase1 we concens in CarBean managed Bean).

You can download my archive project in my attach file. Please add JSF2.0 and richFaces framework to run application (https://community.jboss.org/wiki/HowToAddRichFaces4xToProjectsNotBasedOnMaven)

Here is my application: http://www.mediafire.com/?fnab3824b8vwd93

If you have some problem to download, please contact me. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with `rich:select`. To resolve it, we had to change to `h:selectOneMenu` and add ajax capability for the `onchange` javascript function. Plus, when you're using the ajax approach, you should use `valueChangeListener` in your `h:selectOneMenu` to set the selected value instead of the `value` attribute.

I'll let you a sample

```html
<h:selectOneMenu id="select1" maxListHeight="100" 
    enableManualInput="true" defaultLabel="Type here"
    valueChangeListener="#{carBean.changeCompanyName}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{carBean.lstCompany}"></f:selectItems>
    <a4j:ajax id="ajax1" queueId="queue1" execute="@form"
        render="select2, errorText" event="selectitem"
        listener="#{carBean.changeCompanyEvent()}">
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

In your ManagedBean, you should have a code like this:

```
@ManagedBean(name="carBean")
@ViewScoped
public class CarBean implements Serializable {
    private String companyName;
    //getters and setter...
    //constructor and other functions
    public void valueChangeMethod(ValueChangeEvent e){
        companyName = (String)e.getNewValue();
    }
}
```

There is a post [about this issue](https://community.jboss.org/message/643442) in the RichFaces Forum. Additionally, a BalusC (JSF expert) blog entry about [populating child menu's](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/10/populate-child-menus.html).

Comment: thank you so much about your amazing answer. I'll check it :)

Comment: Hello Luiggi. I tried your suggestion 3 day ago. I still cannot use 2 ajax event yet. The problem appear when I use 2 <a4j:ajax/> and unfortunately with both <rich:select and html select, only one ajax active.